# How do I solve logarithms with addition in them?

Tags: logarithms

I've asked [wolfram alpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=2.5*(e%5E(c*100)%2Be%5E(-c*100))%3D30) to see if there is any solution and in fact there is. Now I just need a way to do this by hand because my school wants me to know such things. So I would really appreciate any help at all, but at best I would like a step by step guide to solve this.

$2.5(e^{c \cdot 100}+e^{-c \cdot 100})=30$

Answer (score 5):

let $$a=e^{100c}$$ then we have $$a+\frac{1}{a}=12$$ and you will get a quadratic equation in $a$.